# Why is my pipe inserting an extra space between writes?

Tags: c++, winapi, io

I have the following simple program. It echos lines until it receives one with a lone `q`.  Then it quits.

```
// quitOnQ.cpp
int main()
{
    string line;
    while (line != "q")
    {
        cout << line << endl;
        getline(cin, line);
    }  
    return 0
}
```

When I launch the program on its own, it works as expected.  However, if I launch it from another program and use an anonymous pipe to write to stdin twice, I get an extra space prefixed to the contents of the second write.

---

#### Manual Run

`j<enter>` -> "j"

`q<enter>` -> [program closes]

#### Piped stdin A (success)

`q\n` -> [program closes]

#### Piped stdin B (success)

`j\nq\n` -> [program closes]

#### Piped stdin C (failure)

`j\n` -> "j"

`q\n` -> " q" [program remains open, notice the extra space]

---

Why does this happen?

Here is the code I am using to write to stdin:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hWriteIN, hReadIN;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saPipe;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo;
    STARTUPINFO procSi;
    DWORD dwWritten, dwRead;

    saPipe.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saPipe.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saPipe.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    // child stdin pipe
    CreatePipe(&hReadIN, &hWriteIN, &saPipe, 0);
    SetHandleInformation(hWriteIN, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);

    ZeroMemory(&procInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    ZeroMemory(&procSi, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    procSi.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    procSi.hStdInput = hReadIN;
    procSi.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    TCHAR args[] = TEXT("quitOnQ.exe");
    CreateProcess(NULL, args, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &procSi, &procInfo);

    this_thread::sleep_for(5s);

    WriteFile(hWriteIN, "j\n", sizeof("j\n"), &dwWritten, NULL);
    WriteFile(hWriteIN, "q\n", sizeof("q\n"), &dwWritten, NULL);
    //WriteFile(hWriteIN, "j\nq\n", sizeof("j\nq\n"), &dwWritten, NULL);

    this_thread::sleep_for(5s);

    CloseHandle(hWriteIN);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `sizeof()` incorrectly.  A `char` string literal is treated as a null-terminated `const char[]` array by the compiler.  Calling `sizeof()` on a string literal *includes the null-terminator* in the size!  `sizeof("j\n")` is 3, not 2 like you are expecting.   That null terminator is where your extra space is coming from.  You should be using `strlen()` instead:

```
WriteFile(hWriteIN, "j\n", strlen("j\n"), &dwWritten, NULL);
WriteFile(hWriteIN, "q\n", strlen("q\n"), &dwWritten, NULL);
```

That being said, you should change your reading loop to this instead:

```
int main()
{
    string line;
    while (getline(cin, line))
    {
        if (line == "q") break;
        cout << line << endl;
    }  
    return 0
}
```

And don't forget to close the handles that `CreateProcess()` returns:

```
CloseHandle(procInfo.hThread);
CloseHandle(procInfo.hProcess);
```

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof("j\n")` will return the length of the string + 1, because it is null terminated. This extra *space* would be that null character.